# Where to find the reference of dos.h for the c programming language?

Tags: c, reference, 16-bit, real-mode, watcom

I'm looking for the reference/documentation of the `dos.h` API.
(especially for an openwatcom specific version).

Where to get the documentation?

Comment: Does something like [This](http://www.digitalmars.com/rtl/dos.html) help?

Comment: This header was used before Al Gore invented the Internet.  This stuff used to be printed on paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reasonable starting point would probably be the [library documentation](http://www.openwatcom.org/ftp/manuals/current/clib.pdf) at OpenWatcom.

Answer (score 0):

http://poli.cs.vsb.cz/c/help/dos.htm

Almost certainly not the original but a good resource anyway

Answer (score 0):

Using the int 21h function reference widely available you could write your own DOS interface routine where the parameters are loaded into the appropriate registers inside the routine.

As I recall I needed three functions: one for character IO (byte register parameters), one for semi-complex (word register parameters - files, memory) and a third which I can no longer remember :(

It's a good exercise!